# Dynamic datalabels Highcharts CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have a `Highcharts` pie chart with a table and two buttons added to it. I need the data labels from the chart to appear dynamically around them, instead of hidden beneath as they are currently.

Is there a way to avoid conflicts with the table overlapping the data labels in `Highcharts`?

Is there a way to do this within the `CSS` or is custom `JavaScript` required?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uf8e3xu/9/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you set your `table` to `z-index: 1`.

Your `Highchart` is an SVG so it has no concept of `z-index`. The type of ordering in SVG is the painters model, meaning each subsequent element is painted over top of the other.

If you really want a table occupying the same space as the chart, I think unfortunately you would have to have the table as elements in the SVG and put it before the `highcharts-data-labels` so that these labels float over the table because they will be "painted after/on top" of the table.